# How to fetch email in the background?

Tags: gnome, email, services, evolution

I use GNOME Evolution as my email and calendar client. It only sends email notifications and event reminders *while Evolution is running*. Is there a way to make the notifications component run in the background so that I still get notified without always having to keep an Evolution window open? I am on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1351149/edit) and add which distro and version of Linux you are running.

Comment: @user68186 That's not a solution, he'd still have an Evolution window open...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On 18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS you can install the [package `evolution-indicator`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/evolution-indicator).
It should provide the functionality you want.

Below is a screen from Synaptic:

[image: Synaptic with Evolution Indicator]